# How to expose Gmail API credentials.json to env

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am writing a gmail data query project in python using google gmail api library and I am using the Gmail API credentials.json file.

How do I store my credentials in a private env so that when others use my script they don't automatically use my gmail credentials.json.

This is what I have tried.
In my .env file, I created a variable CRED

```
CRED={"installed":{"client_id":"##########-#########.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"email-query-#######","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"#############################","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Thereafter, I wrote the following code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

def main():

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:

            config = json.loads(os.environ['CRED']) 
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(config, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        #Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = creds.authorize(http)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http) #  
    # Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])
```

After running the code, I get the below error:

```
<ipython-input-16-d58887cf8862> in <module>
    106 
    107 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 108     main()

<ipython-input-16-d58887cf8862> in main()
     15             #creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
     16 
---> 17             config = json.loads(os.environ['CRED'])
     18             flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(config, SCOPES)
     19             creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    677         except KeyError:
    678             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 679             raise KeyError(key) from None
    680         return self.decodevalue(value)
    681 

KeyError: 'CRED'
```

Let me also point out that I removed the credentials.json from my working directory before running the code.

One more thing, if I leave the credentials.json file in the working directory and run the script, I get the error:

```
 23 
     24     http = httplib2.Http()
---> 25     http = creds.authorize(http)
     26     service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http) #
     27     # Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX

AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

What should I do?

Comment: are you pushing the code to github?

Comment: What "env" do you mean?

Comment: How about using `json.dumps` to your `credentials.json` as a string in environment variable, and load `json.loads` to load the credentials.

Comment: And what have you tried or researched?

Comment: Yes I am pushing it to Github. I want it in a .env file. @PenutChen how do I achieve that?

Comment: You can see the answer below, and pushing your credential to GitHub is dangerous, you need to delete your commit as soon as possible.

Comment: According to your error message, I think you are using Anaconda instead of pipenv. This will be a little different that you need to install `dotenv` package through `pip install python-dotenv`, then add `from dotenv import load_dotenv;load_dotenv()` in the first line of code.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank. I'll go through it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. @PenutChen

Comment: @PenutChen I'm interested in how to fetch a readable part of a message body. You have an idea on how I can go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your `credentials.json` is from [Python Quickstart Gamil API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), and I use this tutorial as exmaple code. I recommend you use `pipenv` so the environment configuration won't be too complex.

First you need to install your virtual environment:

```sh
pip install pipenv
pipenv install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

If you are not prefer to use `pipenv` or you have no idea about how to configure virtual environment, you can install `dotenv` package:

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

Then add these to the head of code:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv;
load_dotenv()
```

Add a file named `.env` under the root of your folder:

```
CRED="Whole JSON String in credentials.json"
```

The enviroment variables in `.env` file will be load when you run your python file from `pipenv run python script.py`.

The original block of code of loading `credentials.json`:

```py
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Should be modify as:

```py
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        config = json.loads(os.environ['CRED'])
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(
            config, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Run your program by `pipenv run python script.py` and you will see a prompt that says `Loading .env environment variables…`.

If you are using version control, you can add `.env` to `.gitignore`, and add a file named `.env.template` which only left a `CRED=` inside it.

Any more detail you can read the document of [pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#automatic-loading-of-env) and [Google authlib](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by whole json string in credentials.json file?

Comment: If you follow the steps of [Python Quickstart Gamil API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), you will get a file named `credential.json`. Open that file, copy all of the text and paste behind `TOKEN=`.

Comment: 17             config = json.loads(os.environ['CRED'])
     18             flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(config, SCOPES)
     19             creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    677         except KeyError:
    678             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 679             raise KeyError(key) from None
    680         return self.decodevalue(value)
    681 

KeyError: 'CRED'

Comment: I copied the credentials.json content to CRED in .env file. I got KeyError: 'CRED' as error after running the script again.

Comment: I have redited my question with the full code and the errors its showing. @PenutChen

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os.getenv('GMAIL_API')` assuming that you already have 'GMAIL_API' variable in your environment.

here is how you can add a variable for each environment:

for windows, you can use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0)

for Linux, you can use [this](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)

Comment: How do I define my GMAIL_API variable?

Comment: How do I achieve this? I have a credentials.json file. I need a clue. @Adam Sherif.